# Flask-Bokeh Servers: Release memory on exit

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, memory-management, flask, gunicorn

I have numerous Bokeh Server files in a directory say.. /dir/bokeh/, assume the bokeh servers are called bokeh1.py, bokeh2.py, bokeh3.py

The file structure is like so:

```
|--dir
    |---flask.py
    |---bokeh
          |--bokeh1.py
          |--bokeh2.py
```

I am deploying them all on flask like so:

```
files=[]
for file in os.listdir("/dir/bokeh/"):
    if file.endswith('.py'):
        file="bokeh/"+file
        files.append(file)

argvs = {}
urls = []
for i in files:
    argvs[i] = None
    urls.append(i.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0])
host = 'myhost.com'

apps = build_single_handler_applications(files, argvs)

bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado(apps, extra_websocket_origins=["myhost.com"])
bokeh_http = HTTPServer(bokeh_tornado)
sockets, port = bind_sockets("myhost.com", 0)
bokeh_http.add_sockets(sockets)
```

Then for each bokeh server, I have within flask.py:

```
@app.route("/bokeh1")
    def bokeh1():
    bokeh_script = server_document("http://11.111.11.111:%d/bokeh1" % port) 
    return render_template("bokserv.html", bokeh_script=bokeh_script)
```

Everything works mostly fine. However, I notice that after closing the bokeh server browser window, the memory associated is not freed. As a result, I need to periodically restart the webserver to replenish memory.

I have tried to use `gc.collect()` ala

```
@app.route("/bokeh1")
    def bokeh1():
    bokeh_script = server_document("http://11.111.11.111:%d/bokeh1" % port) 
    return render_template("bokserv.html", bokeh_script=bokeh_script)
    gc.collect()
```

That does not seem to do the trick however...
How can I Flask/Bokeh to free up memory when the tab/window closes?

Comment: `gc.collect()` won't be called, since you place it after `return` statement.

Comment: I just tried putting it before `return` and after about 10 refreshes, it yields `MemoryError`.

Comment: There are some logging options you can pass to `BokehTornado` to enable much more detailed memory logging: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/server/tornado.html if you enable these do you see messages about uncollected sessions or models?

Comment: within `BokehTornado`, I passed `mem_log_frequency_milliseconds=5000`. There are no logs in the ubuntu terminal though, just messages I'd normally see, i.e. `ColumnDataSource's columns must be same length` and my scripts `print` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After random crashing around, I discovered that this is a gunicorn solution. running the app with the `thread` parameter will release memory back to the Linux when I close pages/tabs in flask

i.e.
`gunicorn -w 2 -t 3 app:app`